# Android Studio stopped working properly for me

Tags: java, android

I installed some new virus protection and removed the one from my laptop. As I had to restart my laptop so that the updates could take effect, It would not restart properly. I ended up having to refresh my laptop to a previous time so that I could once again access my files. I am now downloading the files that I once had, but Android Studio is not allowing me to run the applications that I am trying to test out. I tried to include a screenshot of the issue but I don't have the reputation to do so. The error reads:

Failed to complete Gradle execution.

Cause:
Supplied javaHome is not a valid folder. You supplied: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71

I've tried changing where JAVA_HOME was pointed to but I am still not getting the proper functionality from Android Studio.

Comment: What version of Java is installed on your system?

Comment: Open cmd, type `java -version` . Or, go to `C:\Program Files\Java\ ` and check the version from the folder name. The installed version should be the same as the path you have set in `JAVA_HOME`.

Comment: @JoelFernandes your logic perfect

Comment: @JoelFernandes I will try that when I get back to my laptop. I'm thinking that some of my files did get deleted during the refresh of my laptop. Thank you for your input.

Comment: I checked it and the version was the same as the path. I had copied and pasted the name into the JAVA_HOME path so I know they're the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to install JDK and JRE for x64 and x86 as well.

Comment: What do I do after that?

Comment: Nothing. Installing the both, you just open the Android Studio and check if it still has something missing.